# Icecast Icy headers

Tags: header, icecast

I'm using icecast with a bunch of mountpoints to broadcast local radio stations for our customers. For some of them we fetch the current playing song and update the metadata info on icecast every few seconds using the /admin/metadata URI.

However, I've noticed that some players like VLC or iTunes apprently seem to go for the ICY headers in the HTTP request (ICY Info: StreamTitle=....)

I am now wondering if there is a way to set these headers on the icecast server in a similar way like the metadata uri, or how would anyone set these headers? Icecast seems not to set the ICY headers if I update the metadata of the mountpoint.

Thanks and regards

Comment: The metadata is send in an set interval, so it may take a while till it reflects the metadata change

Answer (score 0):

VLC and iTunes both want the metadata at regular intervals, just like any other SHOUTcast/Icecast clients.  If this isn't working, whatever code you have updating the metadata on Icecast isn't working.

Comment: It uses to work just that way it is working now. I can also see in the playlist log that the song information is set on the mountpoint. This used to work just fine, but I really cant figure out what changed since there was no change of configuration.

Comment: @Tobi I couldn't really help you figure that out since you didn't post any code or headers or anything for how you're updating that metadata.  All I can tell you is that it is on the source end somewhere.